# angularjs using $on and $broadcast to communicate between a master controller to another controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I am trying to set communication between two angular controllers (service is not an option). and I am failing desperately.

here is some of my code...
i tried using both $emit and $broadcast

```
invoiceApp.controller('masterReportConrtoller', ['$scope', '$location', 'authService', 'usSpinnerService', 'dateService', 'settingsService','$rootScope',
function ($scope, $location, authService, usSpinnerService, dateService, settingsService, $rootScope ) 
 ////Is User Valid
    ////
    //$rootScope.$on("masterReportConrtoller", function () {
    //        $scope.parentmethod();
    //    });
    //$scope.parentmethod = function () {
    //    //
    $scope.masterReportConrtoller.getUserDetails = function () {
        debugger;
            settingsService.getUserDetails().then(function (response) {
                var loginData = {
                    userName: response.d.user.Email,
                    password: response.d.user.UserPassword

                };
            authService.login(loginData).then(function (response) {
                debugger;
                $scope.Limit = response.d.organization.Limit;
            });
            $scope.Limit = response.d.organization.Limit;
            $scope.DocumentUsage = response.d.organization.DocumentUsage;
            $scope.ExpirationDate = $scope.DateConvertfromJson(response.d.organization.ExpirationDate);
            var fullDate = new Date();
            if (fullDate <= $scope.ExpirationDate) {
                $scope.ISvalidUser = false;
                $rootScope.$broadcast('masterReportConrtoller', false);
            }
            else {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('masterReportConrtoller', true);
            }
        });
    }   
}]);


invoiceApp.controller('InvoiceController', ['$scope', '$location', '$cookieStore', 'documentService', 'dialogs', 'usSpinnerService', 'settingsService', 'associatedEmailsService', '$rootScope',
function ($scope, $location, $cookieStore, documentService, dialogs, usSpinnerService, settingsService, associatedEmailsService, $rootScope) {


 $rootScope.$on('masterReportConrtoller');}
```

Comment: You should have a callback function to handle when the event is emitted. `$rootScope.$on('masterReportConrtoller', function(event, data){ // do something with data});`.

Comment: can i use the event of the page loading?

Comment: `event` in this case is the actual event that has been triggered with `$rootScope.$broadcast('masterReportConrtoller', false);`.

Comment: so if i dont have an event, what would you advise?

Comment: You can easily trigger your own custom event with, for example `$rootScope.broadcast("myCustomEvent", { something: "data that will be sent"});` and then, catch that event with `$rootScope.$on('myCustomEvent', function(event, data){ // do something with data});`. However, if you only need this parent - child controller communication, you should avoid using `$rootScope`. You have everything explained in this link: https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/ .

Comment: tank you very much ! ! !

Comment: No problem :). I will paste this as an answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your parent - child controller relationship, you can use `$scope.$broadcast` and `$scope.$on` in your code.

Try something like this:

```
//masterReportConrtoller
$scope.$broadcast("myCustomEvent", { isValidUser: false });

//InvoiceController
$scope.$on("myCustomEvent" , function(event, data){
   //do something with data
});
```

Please note that this will work if `masterReportConrtoller` is the parent controller and `InvoiceController` is the child controller. If this is not the case, then use `$rootScope.$broadcast` and `$rootScope.$on`.

You can find more details [here](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$localStorage` , `$stateParams`  or `$cookies` or even ... I generally prefer `$stateParams` to send values and object to states and controller.

```
$state.go('state2', { someParam : 'broken magic' });
```

read file using  `$stateParams` from controller . Details can be found [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)